# Scala API for generating Swagger files?

Tags: scala, swagger-2.0

I'm looking for a way to programmatically generating Swagger (JSON and/or YAML) output files, from Scala. This would really be a simple use for case classes, but I wonder if such a project already is around, i.e. a typed way of making the API schema.

Most solutions seem to extract the interface from annotations, but I would need to create arbitrary Swagger output - not directly tied to the route implementation of my service. For this, I haven't found a ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you're running a play application, i've found this to be super useful: http://iheartradio.github.io/play-swagger/

it generates the swagger docs by analyzing your routes file.

Comment: I'm not running Play and my use case is not about documenting the particular service's API (as I tried to phrase in the question: "I would need to create arbitrary Swagger output"). There may be something inside play-swagger that I could use, but otherwise your answer is not to the particular question.

Comment: my bad, i guess i misunderstood. perhaps you could elaborate on exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Scala case classes that would mirror the Swagger 2.0 syntax, so that I can create the definition tree in code, then output as JSON or YAML.